# Error in data-binding database to web form

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

i am a beginner in making website, i learned things at msdn only, but now when i try to make a very simple Website, i am having this error

"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV5qY.jpg

steps followed to create the web site > New WebSite>Empty Website>Add new WebForm>Dragged The GridView on the page >Added new data source(sdf format).

The test query runs fine, but when i try to run the webPage, i am having this error, i have spent the whole previous day searching for a solution(but they seem to be valid no more, or are for older versions). 
I am using Vs2010 ultimate, got sqlServer compact edition 2008 SP2 installed. 
Here is the Web.config file :

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Users\TarunG\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\Database1.sdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
 </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"></compilation>
  </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

The database contains only one Table - Result1.
 The default.aspx file :

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    </div>
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="Roll No." DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Roll No." HeaderText="Roll No." ReadOnly="True"
        SortExpression="Roll No." />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category"
        SortExpression="Category" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Rank" HeaderText="Rank" SortExpression="Rank" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Registration No." HeaderText="Registration No."
        SortExpression="Registration No." />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Result1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
  </form>
</body>
```

---

machine.config :

```
<add name="SQL Server Compact Edition Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc" type="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for OleDb" type="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OracleClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" type="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
   <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a web site, you should be using SQL Server Express, not SQL Server Compact Edition.  SQL Server Compact Edition is designed for standalone, single-user scenarios.  ASP.NET is looking for the SQL Server Express drivers and not finding them.

I suggest uninstalling SQL Server Compact Edition, then installing SQL Server Express from here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/  That will also install the necessary drivers.

With SS Express installed, make your web.config connection string look like this:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="Microsoft.Sql.Client.3.5" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: But the problem is that the database is in sdf format, will that wont create a problem

Comment: i already have a microsoft SQL server 2008 installed(it isn't specified which version it is ). Shall i still download the Express version??

Comment: If you already have SS2008 installed, then you're fine. You're probably just having a connection string issue. You need to know the name of the server and the name of the SS2008 instance, if any. Then you can construct your connection string properly:

Comment: As a self-proclaimed beginner, I would suggest you install SQL Server Express for learning purposes.  Many of the Visual Studio templates and examples assume you have Express in place, running on your local host, under instance name SQLEXPRESS.  I'll update my answer with an example of how your connection string should look in that scenario.

Comment: what should the ./SQLEXPRESS be changed with if i wish to use the non-express version?? (there is nothing like that specifies the flavour of SS)

Comment: At the time you installed SQL Server, you would have had an option to install it with an instance name, or as the default instance.  If you specified and instance name, replace SQLEXPRESS with that.  If you specified the default instance, omit /SQLEXPRESS entirely.  Use DataSource=localhost instead.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx, your Connection String should be something like:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

btw, you need SQL Server Express for the above line to work.

Comment: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" /> -- still not working